# meaning ielts question

Tags: grammar, meaning, ielts

What does this sentence mean : (I don't understand the phrase " **the highest earning exports** ")

**sentence** : petroleum products were the highest earning exports in both years

Answer (score 4):

“Highest earning” is an adjectival phrase modifying “exports”. It means that petroleum products were the exports that earned the most money.

It would be clearer with a hyphen: “Petroleum products were the highest-earning exports”.